# Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: TabsPage

Tags: ionic2, ionic-tabs

I am making ecommerce app in ionic2. While using tabs page I am getting below Runtime error

> Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: TabsPage

tabs.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { WishlistPage } from '../wishlist/wishlist';
import { AccountPage } from '../account/account';


@IonicPage({
  name: 'TabsPage'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  tab1Root: any = HomePage;
  tab2Root: any = WishlistPage;
  tab3Root: any = AccountPage;
  myIndex:number

  tab1Title = " ";
  tab2Title = " ";
  tab3Title = " ";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public translateService: TranslateService) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Are the `HomePage` etc Ionic Page? lazy loaded? and where is TabsPage set?

Comment: After adding tab.module.ts it's keep getting loading but nothing happens

Comment: can you add the code where TabsPage is pushed to nav?

Comment: I have the same error with ionic 3

Comment: @hous well I just found solution in my code itself. There was some typo error in my code which was causing me issue. In my case I have used page="true" which was wrong. Correct was pager-"true"